# MongoDB query really slow when wrapped in $query operator

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB which has about 350k documents. I have compound index on `Updated` (descending) and `SecondaryCategories` (ascending).

```
db.Content.ensureIndex({ "Updated" : -1, "SecondaryCategories" : 1 },{ "name" : "Updated_SecondaryCategories", "background" : true });
```

I'm using MongoDB C# driver to build a query using lambda syntax:

```
IQueryable<Content> query = repo.GetAll()
            .Where(
                x =>
                    x.SecondaryCategories.ContainsAny(sel) &&
                    (x.Type == ContentType.News || x.Type == ContentType.FotoNews || x.Type == ContentType.LinkedNews || x.Type == ContentType.MediaNews) &&
                    x.Texts.Any(y => (int)y.Language == cultureId))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Skip(skipItems)
            .Take(count);
```

and I'm getting the following:

```
db.Content.find({ "$query" : { "SecondaryCategories" : { "$in" : [524, 615, 550, 546, 552, 617, 547, 549, 548, 613, 614, 551, 618, 545] }, "$or" : [{ "Type" : 4 }, { "Type" : 8 }, { "Type" : 32 }, { "Type" : 16 }], "Texts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Language" : 0 } } }, $orderby: { Updated: -1 }}).limit(20);
```

The query runs approximately for 1300ms which is rather slow. Now, when I remove the `$query` operator, I should get the following:

```
db.Content.find({ "SecondaryCategories" : { "$in" : [524, 615, 550, 546, 552, 617, 547, 549, 548, 613, 614, 551, 618, 545] }, "$or" : [{ "Type" : 4 }, { "Type" : 8 }, { "Type" : 32 }, { "Type" : 16 }], "Texts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Language" : 0 } }}).sort({"Updated" : -1}).limit(20);
```

That query runs just in 1ms.

Explain for the first query (with `$query` operator):

```
db.Content.find({ "$query" : { "SecondaryCategories" : { "$in" : [524, 615, 550, 546, 552, 617, 547, 549, 548, 613, 614, 551, 618, 545] }, "$or" : [{ "Type" : 4 }, { "Type" : 8 }, { "Type" : 32 }, { "Type" : 16 }], "Texts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Language" : 0 } } }, $orderby: { Updated: -1 }, $explain: 1 }).limit(20).pretty();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Updated_SecondaryCategories multi",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 188173,
    "nscannedObjects" : 188668,
    "nscanned" : 337619,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 189056,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 338007,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1304,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "Updated" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "SecondaryCategories" : [
                    [
                            524,
                            524
                    ],
                    [
                            545,
                            545
                    ],
                    [
                            546,
                            546
                    ],
                    [
                            547,
                            547
                    ],
                    [
                            548,
                            548
                    ],
                    [
                            549,
                            549
                    ],
                    [
                            550,
                            550
                    ],
                    [
                            551,
                            551
                    ],
                    [
                            552,
                            552
                    ],
                    [
                            613,
                            613
                    ],
                    [
                            614,
                            614
                    ],
                    [
                            615,
                            615
                    ],
                    [
                            617,
                            617
                    ],
                    [
                            618,
                            618
                    ]
            ]
    }
```

And for the second (without `$query` operator):

```
db.Content.find({ "SecondaryCategories" : { "$in" : [524, 615, 550, 546, 552, 617, 547, 549, 548, 613, 614, 551, 618, 545] }, "$or" : [{ "Type" : 4 }, { "Type" : 8 }, { "Type" : 32 }, { "Type" : 16 }], "Texts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Language" : 0 } }}).sort({"Updated" : -1}).limit(20).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Updated_SecondaryCategories multi",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 20,
    "nscannedObjects" : 29,
    "nscanned" : 69,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 94,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 134,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "Updated" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "SecondaryCategories" : [
                    [
                            524,
                            524
                    ],
                    [
                            545,
                            545
                    ],
                    [
                            546,
                            546
                    ],
                    [
                            547,
                            547
                    ],
                    [
                            548,
                            548
                    ],
                    [
                            549,
                            549
                    ],
                    [
                            550,
                            550
                    ],
                    [
                            551,
                            551
                    ],
                    [
                            552,
                            552
                    ],
                    [
                            613,
                            613
                    ],
                    [
                            614,
                            614
                    ],
                    [
                            615,
                            615
                    ],
                    [
                            617,
                            617
                    ],
                    [
                            618,
                            618
                    ]
            ]
    }
```

I can't really understand this difference in query behavior. It seems like the first query scans through 338k documents and returns 188173 which is then limited, while the second scans only 69.

Is my index wrong or do I have to rewrite the query? Is there any way to compose queries without the `$query` operator using C# MongoDB Driver?

Comment: Did you try explaining the query?  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/query/#op._S_query - i imagine you may need to add the limit clause to the query document itself rather than do `.limit`

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `$explain : 1` to explain the first query. And I can't find any other ways to limit. There is `$maxScan` but it just limits the number of documents scanned.

Answer (score 0):

in the [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/query/#op._S_query) the state that

> Do not mix query forms. If you use the $query format, do not append
>   cursor methods to the find(). To modify the query use the meta-query
>   operators, such as $explain.

so in your case I think it is the `.limit(20)` use that is omitted and causes your query to keep looking in all the collection for all the documents.

Maybe it is a bug on the `c#` driver.

Comment: I can't find any meta-query operator for `limit()`. There is the `$maxScan`operator, but according to the manual: `Constrains the query to only scan the specified number of documents when fulfilling the query.`. So it only prevents Mongo from scanning more than the specified number of documents in the whole index race. I can never be sure if it returns my needed 20 documents.

Comment: I don't see it either... I just want to point out, that it is the `limit` usage (or not) that affects the performance. Try removing it from both queries and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since there is no meta-query operator for `limit()` and `$maxScan` has a different meaning, I will just have to put a condition on Updated field, for example greater than last month: `"Updated" : {$gte : new ISODate("2013-12-29T00:00:01Z")}`. This way my query will return in just 50ms. In case there are less documents returned than the limit, I can extend the date filter and run the query again.